# Need resutls upto two decimal i.e seconds and miliseconds in jmeter

Tags: function, jmeter, performance-testing, beanshell, post-processor

I want to add my summary report results in the email body. So I have added the bean shell post-processor against my request and add the below functions in it.

```
*<BeanShellPostProcessor guiclass="TestBeanGUI" testclass="BeanShellPostProcessor" testname="BeanShell PostProcessor" enabled="true">
            <boolProp name="resetInterpreter">false</boolProp>
            <stringProp name="parameters"></stringProp>
            <stringProp name="filename"></stringProp>
            <stringProp name="script">float duration = prev.getTime()/1000;
                 
props.put(&quot;getDTS_response&quot;, String.valueOf(duration));</stringProp>
          </BeanShellPostProcessor>*
```

Funtion used in mail body:

```
*&quot;Request 1 Reponse    ${__property(getDTS_response,0)} Seconds&quot;*
```

Now when I receive the results in the mail body, those are displayed as below.

Summary Report Result against request # 1:  8563

Result against request 1 in mail body: 8.0 seconds

Summary Report Result against request # 2:  354

Result against request 1 in mail body: 0.0 seconds

I want my results as below:

Result against request 1 in mail body: 8.563 seconds

Result against request 2 in mail body: 0.354 seconds

Please guide in resolving the issue.

Thanks and Regards

Answer (score 0):

[Since JMeter 3.1 you should be using JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) for scripting so I'll provide a Groovy solution:

```
(prev.getTime() / 1000).round(3)
```

Demo:

[image]

More information:

- [Groovy Goodness: Round and Truncate Decimal Values](https://blog.mrhaki.com/2010/01/groovy-goodness-round-and-truncate.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)